# Access current item in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The following Control is bound to a List of Users:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Users">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
```

How can I pass the user to a Converter in this case, not just properties of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're referring to an `IValueConverter` instance?
Just leave out the Path parameter of your Binding and it will pass in the current `DataContext` (in your case a `User` instance).

This sample assumes your `IValueConverter` is called `MyValueConverter`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Users">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBox Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyValueConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```